# Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas.node' Discord bot Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

The bot worked perfectly until one day (without touching anything) it stopped working and I got this error in the node_modules folder:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas.node'
Require stack:
- /home/container/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js
- /home/container/node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js
- /home/container/node_modules/canvas/index.js
- /home/container/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/container/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js',
    '/home/container/node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js',
    '/home/container/node_modules/canvas/index.js',
    '/home/container/index.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you got canvas installed?

Comment: How i can install canvas?

Comment: You can use `npm install canvas` as shown in the npm readme [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)

Comment: I installed canvas but don`t work